# I cant see my windows drive in ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, wubi, windows-7, mount, drive

I'm n00ber than any n00b you ever seen, so bear with me...

I just downloaded `wubi` and installed ubuntu 12.10 along with Windows 7 on the same HDD.

Linux works fine, but doesnt show files from drive `C` (on which it is installed). I really need `C` as it contains all my files.
I did `df  -h` in the terminal. It does show the drive.

```
/dev/sda2       577G  220G  358G  38% /host
```

Now I tried to mount the drive

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2
```

and got the response

```
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /host busy  
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda2 is already mounted on /host
```

I dont know what that means. The drive doesnt show up in `HOME FOLDER`.
What am i supposed to do now?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 usually mounts drives in /media/username/drive_label. See if you can find your files there.

Comment: I think its mounted under /host, Go to file manager, then press Ctrl+L and type: /host

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Computer' instead. You may find it there. If not, check any drives that are in that folder. If any drives have 'Intel' or 'Documents and settings' (Or something like that) then that might be your C drive. First,  write down the drive's name, then write down some of those folders in that drive. Then go to Windows 7 and check if the folders match. If they do, go to Ubuntu and rename the drive to 'C drive' (Or something like that). If not, I can not help you.